# Bad character using curl in php

Tags: php, json, curl

I have this url [DespegarAPI](http://api.despegar.com/cities?pagesize=30) and as you can see the content is OK. Is a JSON response.

I need that content through my own file and I use curl o file_content but the response I this [my file](http://ushuaiamovil.com.ar/api/devolverCiudadesDespegar.php)

I have this in my file

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.despegar.com/cities?pagesize=30");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Thanks for the response!

Comment: The is the definition for the URL http://api.despegar.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the content is gzipped, here's a quick example to get you going.

```
<?php
function despegar($endpoint, array $params = array()) {

    $url = sprintf(
        'http://api.despegar.com/%s?%s',
        $endpoint,
        empty($params) ? null : http_build_query($params)
    );

    $handle = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => 'gzip',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true
    ));

    $response   = curl_exec($handle);
    $code       = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( ! $response || 200 != $code) {
        throw new Exception(
            sprintf('(%d) Failed to obtain data from %s.', $code, $url),
            $code
        );
    }

    return json_decode($response);
}

try {
    $cities = despegar('cities', array('pagesize' => 10));

    foreach ($cities->cities as $city) {
        printf("%s\n", $city->countryId);
    }
}catch(Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is not working...http://ushuaiamovil.com.ar/api/devolverCiudadesDespegar.php

Comment: I don't know what the content of your script is, but the example I posted *definitely* works. Increase error reporting on your host and start debugging.

Comment: I put some outputs and is working now. At least I see some results now. The problem now is the daily limit of request of the api.